# How can I start multiple tabs in Windows 11 terminal with bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal

how can I run 3 bat files at once in multiple tabs in the windows 11 terminal?
I have a bat file with this content:

```
start "User Service" cmd /c "run UserSevice.bat"
start "SMCQ.WebApi" cmd /c "run SMCQ.WebApi.bat"
start "GeneralData.WebApi" cmd /c "run SMCQ.GeneralData.WebApi.bat"
```

I also saw that people use also some JSON files to start many files, does somebody have an instruction to create these files to run complicated commands?

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows

```
wt file1.bat; file2.bat; file3.bat
```

or

```
wt ^
file1.bat; ^
file2.bat; ^
file3.bat
```